# how to capture listfield scroll to bottom in blackberry 7

Tags: blackberry

I have a listfield with many data, at first i load 10 records from server, i want to capture the event when the scroll has moved to bottom, that i can load more records from server.

I implements ScrollChangeListener:

```
public class DataListScreen extends MainScreen implements ScrollChangeListener {
    public void scrollChanged(Manager manager, int newHorizontalScroll, int newVerticalScroll) {
        System.out.println(getVirtualHeight()); // 480
        System.out.println(getVisibleHeight()); // 480
        System.out.println(newVerticalScroll); // 0 - 1259
    }
}
```

but i do know how to get vertical scroll max size?

Any ideas? Please help me.

Comment: add a load more button at the bottom of your list. When you click that button, add next 10 records to your list. and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ListField`, and you are performing custom painting by extending `ListFieldCallback`, then you can detect that a row is focused inside the `drawListRow` method:

```
    public void drawListRow(ListField lf, Graphics g, int index, int y, int x) {

        if (lf.isFocus() && lf.getSelectedIndex() == index) {
            //The selected row is bein repainted

            if(index == (lf.getSize() - 1)){
                //The last row is being focused
            }
        }

    }
```

Then you can request new elements in a worker thread. Block the GUI with a loading message.

This is a basic solution to the problem. In a real pro app, you'd preemtively request a new batch of elements when the user is about to reach the end of the list (selected row = size of the list - number of rows that fit in the screen). This way it can scroll down without waiting. You'd have to handle failed requests as well as multiple user initiated requests over the same batch.