# Pull to refresh Listview and load in Blackberry

Tags: listview, blackberry

I need to implement pull to refresh and load in listview. How could i implement pull to refresh and load in listview in Blackberry using java.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: @Signare i am just trying,could you give any idea

Comment: Have you tried with scrolling listerer ?

Comment: @HrushikeshSalkade no.

Answer (score 0):

override navigationMovement() of Manager of ListField. Then

```
Field ff = getLeafFieldWithFocus();
        if( ff instanceof ListField ){
            ListField compo = (ListField)ff;
            int index = compo.getSelectedIndex();
            if( index == compo.getSize() - 1 ){
                // POST YOUR LOGIC HERE !!!
            }
        }
```

EDIT ::
OR

```
public void drawListRow(ListField lf, Graphics g, int index, int y, int x) {

        if (lf.isFocus() && lf.getSelectedIndex() == index) {
            if(index == (lf.getSize() - 1)){
                //The last row is being focused. Load NEW data here !!!
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The last snippet is suspiciously similar to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16337882/813951).