# How To Create a lazy list with images in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How to create a lazy list with images in blackberry 7.1 plz help me

I have created a custom list view and i am passing a bitmap and title text to that custom list view it is displaying it .but i want load the images after loading the list in blackberry as like lazy list in android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to capture listfield scroll to bottom in blackberry 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333686/how-to-capture-listfield-scroll-to-bottom-in-blackberry-7).  I know the title doesn't sound the same, but it's essentially the same problem, and the answer given is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [ListFieldCallback](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListFieldCallback.html). In `drawListRow` load images when necessary and draw them. If an image is already loaded, then just draw it, if not, load it before drawing.

And check this tutorial: http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=898